# JFugue 5.0.4 loading Synthesizer does not work

Tags: java, jfugue

I was doing some really cool stuff with JFugue 4.0.3 when 5 came and I noticed it came with lots of new features.
Now trying to move some code to jfugue 5.0.4 I see that my external soundfont is not being loaded, even when trying it in the new way (using the SynthesizerManager). From what I have read, on using the setSynthesizer method from SynthesizerManager all players would have that Synthesizer loaded by default, but I only hear the default piano sounds. I tested loading the Synthesizer alone and listing the instruments and it works, so I guess the problem is having the SynthesizerManager set the correct Synthesizer to players.

```
        Soundbank coolGuitars = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new File("/music/guitar.sf2"));

        Synthesizer synt = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synt.open();
        synt.loadAllInstruments(coolGuitars);

        SynthesizerManager s = SynthesizerManager.getInstance();
        s.setSynthesizer(synt);

        Player player = new Player();
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C+E+G D+F+A E+G+B F+A+C G+B+D A+C+E B+D+F");
        pattern.setInstrument(0);

        player.play(pattern);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You are using the API as intended. Looks like it's a bug in the JFugue code. I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to merge all my soundfonts into one and replaced the default java soundfont to work around that, but ideally I would load each soundfont and choose the instruments to use from each one in code.